# Unable to create database via mongo compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

Creating a database within mongodb and it throws topology error.

topology destroyed

Attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Topology was destroyed` error comes, when mongodb was writing something and connection was closed/interrupted in middle.

Have a look at the [code](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/blob/V2.2.1/lib/topologies/mongos.js#L664) which throws this error :

```
Mongos.prototype.insert = function(ns, ops, options, callback) {
  if(typeof options == 'function') callback = options, options = {}, options = options || {};
  if(this.state == DESTROYED) return callback(new MongoError(f('topology was destroyed')));

  // Not connected but we have a disconnecthandler
  if(!this.isConnected() && this.s.disconnectHandler != null) {
    return this.s.disconnectHandler.add('insert', ns, ops, options, callback);
  }

  // No mongos proxy available
  if(!this.isConnected()) {
    return callback(new MongoError('no mongos proxy available'));
  }

  // Execute write operation
  executeWriteOperation(this, 'insert', ns, ops, options, callback);
}
```

**Solution :**

**Kindly restart your mongodb and MongoDB compass as well, just to be on the safer side**, and you should be able to create collections without any error.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I moved to robot 3t as I was waiting and it works fine now, I think it's the compass that's the culprit

Comment: The issue was the conneciton made to mongodb via compass, but not the compass itself. You can get the same error with robo3T as well (speaking from personal experience) . You just need to create a new connection(restart robo3t/compass), and continue with your query. sometimes you might need to restart mongodb as well.